# SQL Server get parent list

Tags: sql-server, hierarchy

I have a table like this:

```
id name parent_id
1  ab1  3
2  ab2  5
3  ab3  2
4  ab4  null
5  ab5  null
6  ab6  null
```

I need to do a query with input id = 1 (for an example) and results will be like this:

```
id name parent_id
5  ab5  null
2  ab2  5
3  ab3  2
1  ab1  3
```

(List all parents at all level start at item id = 1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
    WITH parents(id,name,parent,level)
    AS
    (
    SELECT
       ID,
       NAME,
       PARENT,
       0 as level
    FROM
       TABLE
    WHERE ID = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
       ID,
       NAME,
       PARENT,
       Level + 1
    FROM 
       TABLE
    WHERE
       id = (SELECT TOP 1 parent FROM parents order by level desc)
    )
    SELECT * FROM parents
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `WITH RECURSIVE`. Documentation and adaptable example: [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx).