# displaying parent and child menu names

Tags: asp.net

Using SQL I want to return a list of menu names from single menutable that has field structure:MenuEntry,intmenu,Name,URL,intsubmenu

I am passing * as wildcard at the beginning and end of URL as search keyword in textbox,I looked at the solutions present in [get a recursive parent list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569399/get-a-recursive-parent-list) but my table consist of intsubmenu(child id) and also I need to display the menus in the format 
    root menu > submenu1 > submenu2 while clicking on search button.

```
    menuEntry   intMenu   description        URL               intSubMenu
    1          1001     Showroom            /portal/default.aspx     1002
    2          1002     Sales               /sales/index.html         0
    3          1002     Aftersales          /aftersales/index.html    0
    4          1002     Admin               /bin/usrmgmt/Admin.aspx  1003
    5          1003     Homepage            /bin/usrmgmt/homepage.asp 0
    6          1003     Menu               /bin/usrmgmt/menu.asp      0
    7          1003     Content            /bin/usrmgmt/content.aspx  0

Enter :*usrmgmt*
OUTPUT: Showroom > Admin > Homepage
Showroom > Admin > Menu
Showroom > Admin > Content

To be more specific,if I enter *parent-list* in textbox,
it should fetch me the list of menus like stackoverflow.com > questions > 7569399 > get-a-recursive-parent-list
```